# ExecuteTemplate convert plus(+) sign to &#43; in like with email arguments

Tags: go, go-templates

I have a function to send verify email with link with hash and email as parameters but when call `ExecuteTemplate` function it converts + sign which is in the mail to + symbol. link type is `template.URL`

Here is the link to both files.

[grpc.go](https://github.com/GirishBhutiya/gocomm-micro/blob/main/mailer-service/cmd/api/grpc.go#L20) and [mailer.go](https://github.com/GirishBhutiya/gocomm-micro/blob/main/mailer-service/cmd/api/mailer.go#L17)

and below is the screenshot of log.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: &#43; is a valid encoding of + in HTML, just like &amp; is an encoding for &. If you want to render plain text use text/template, not html/template.

Comment: ok I will try it and let you know.